# Renaming files in directory with various endings on Mac?

Tags: unix, batch-file

Trying to rename a set of files in a directory with various filetypes, all with one common word, say 'foo', to another word, say 'bar' on a MacBook Pro.

E.g.:

```
foo.txt

form_foo.plist

home_foo.png

images_foo.zip
```

->

```
bar.txt

form_bar.plist

home_bar.png

images_bar.zip
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use with care:

```
ls | grep foo | while read -r name; do echo mv "$name" "${name//foo/bar}"; done
```

That will report the commands it will run when you omit "echo".  Inspect
the results, then rerun with "echo" omitted.  This makes no attempt to work
on files with newlines in the name, nor does it recurse into subdirectories.  If you want to work with files whose name begins with `.`, add `-a` to the invocation of `ls`.  For safety's sake, you may want to add `-i` to the invocation of `mv`.  Certainly make a backup first.

Comment: Thanks! Works as intended.
I also tried a software from [Renamer](http://renamer.com/). It does the job, but is only free as trial for 14 days.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a Mac, but under Ubuntu you can use the `rename` command for this. Here's the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rename) in case that command is available

Comment: No, the `rename`command wasn't built in. Even if it was I wasn't able to figure out a command that would do the type of find and replace functionality I was looking for.